# Cost-effective options for global geographic load balancing?

Tags: load-balancing

We run a website that receives about 1 million visitors a month and aprox 2 million page views per month, with about 40% of the traffic from India, 40% from the US and balance from the rest of the world. Our servers are in US and we are thinking of locating one server in India or in Singapore to decrease latency and improve our page load times for Indian visitors. We would like to maintain a single domain name for all visitors. So   we are looking at Geographic Load Balancing solutions. But the cost of doing this seems to be prohibitively high if we use a hardware based solution from our provider. We have been looking for more cost-effective options if they exist.

Comment: Update : We have been looking at various Geographic load balancing options - including those from Edgedirector.com and Tzoha.com. Please see my comment to the answer below. Anyone who has used either service please do share your experience.

Answer (score 4):

Your situation sounds like it would be a good fit for geographically-aware DNS.  That kind of service checks the source IP of the DNS query (which is usually a recursive resolver belonging to the ISP that the client is connecting from), determines its geographic location, and responds with an address for your server that varies depending on the geographic location of the client.

The major caveat with this approach is that if the client is using a DNS server in a different geographical location than themselves, or the location of the resolver they're using isn't correct in the geo-IP database, then the user may be sent to servers on the wrong side of the world.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, in fact, we are currently looking at a few geographically aware DNS services. The ones we have found so far are  from Edgedirector.com and Tzoha.com.  Both seem pretty reasonably priced and offer geo-load balancing as well as failover.  One difference is that while Edgecaster uses the DNS resolver's IP address (which could be different from the client's geo location) Tzocha uses the originating client IP address to direct the client to the closest server geographically. Anyone with experience with either - we would love to hear from them.

Comment: @Ron Server Fault does not do product and service recommendations (in fact, ["shopping" questions are generally off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). We could tell you that Joe's DNS Service is the best ever, and the next day Joe sells his business to Crazy McKrakken's Cut Rate Cactus Nameserver Farm and we wouldn't put our worst enemy's DNS on his servers. All we can really do is tell you which techniques to consider - you need to pick a vendor yourself after talking to them & reviewing the contract/terms of service.